# Does the sentence "This bleak picture" makes sense?

Tags: phrases, expressions, writing-advice

i'm not an english native speaker and i'm writing lyrics in english.

I've came across the sentence "This bleak picture" but i'm wondering -even though it might be grammaticaly correct and that everybody gets the meaning of it- that this sentence might be some kind of poor translation and that it's not really said in common english language.

It has been used to describe a dark situation, like an aftermath. Someone would say "This bleak picture reminds us of......."
And might have a double meaning, to describe a dark painting.

And if it's not, do you think that it can fit in a poem, where you have more freedom about meaning and grammar?

Thank you.

Comment: It's a perfectly valid phrase. What do you think it is a 'poor translation' of?

Comment: I had a false belief that Bleak would not really apply in this context.

Comment: Even if it didn't make sense in standard English (which it does), if you're using it in a poem or song lyrics you have more flexibility in both grammar and meaning.

Comment: Ok thanks a lot everyone!

Comment: Look here: https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/bleak-picture  Btw, just google "bleak picture" under "News" and see. Good Luck.